# MVC5 Change Database and Entity Model Classes dynamically

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I am able to switch between the databases dynamically by using following code:

```
public MyEntities() : base("name=MyEntities")
{
}
```

But this still uses the old Model classes. I read somewhere that the model classes should be same in order to switch to different databases. But I particularly need to change/reload the model classes each time the database changes.

FYI, I need to do this because the development database schema keeps on changing while the Stage and Production are quite stable. Since the Models are generated using Development database hence they are different than Production/Stage classes.

Comment: There are literally a bazillion blog posts on how to correctly generate a database model using Code First or the older Database First methodologies.

Comment: I don't think so you understood my question. I know how to generate the Model classes. I am not able to switch between the Model classes(when the schema is different) of different version of databases at runtime.

Comment: I don't understand. Stage and Production are *supposed* to match different versions of your software. Why would you ever want to connect to a Stage database (let alone Prod) from dev? If there is any reason to do that you should use upgraded copies of the Stage/Prod database.

Answer (score 1):

The short version is that you're thinking about it incorrectly. You can't just point your connection string to a DB with a different schema: it doesn't work that way, and would break all your code if it did. You need to keep your code schema in sync with your DB schema. If you really have (say) three different database schemas that you need to talk to at the same time, you need three different code schemas.

In other words, if you're working on some code that's supposed to run against your local dev DB, which has a different schema than your production DB, you can't just change the connection string and point it to the production DB. It won't run, and it shouldn't.

If you really need to run/write/debug code against the production DB in that scenario, you should have a "Production" (or Master) branch which has the correct code schema matching the production DB schema, and switch over to that branch when writing that sort of code (say, for a patch or something). Then, when you've submitted the patch to master, you can merge that commit back into your development branch, and carry on.